# Is it possible to have "inherited partial structs" in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to use partial structs to achieve something like this:
Have an asp.net page base class with the following defined:

```
public partial struct QuerystringKeys
{
    public const string Username = "username";
    public const string CurrentUser = "currentUser";
}
```

Have an asp.net page, which inherits from the base class mentioned above, extend the partial declaration:

```
public partial struct QuerystringKeys
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The page number of the review instances list
    /// </summary>
    public const string Page = "page";
}
```

The final goal is a QuerystringKeys struct with all three constant strings defined in it available to the asp.net page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. When you are taliking about the ASP .NET pages, I assume you want the struct to be contained within the page class declaration (if not, why don't you just put it in a separate code file) ?

If your struct is only intended to hold constant strings, use a class and inherit from the base. Since you won't be creating instances of it, there will be no difference:

```
public class Test : Page
{
    internal class QuerystringKeys : BasePage.QuerystringKeys
    {            
        public const string Page = "page";
    }
}

public class BasePage : Page
{
    internal class QuerystringKeys
    {
        public const string Username = "username";
        public const string CurrentUser = "currentUser";
    }
}
```

Comment: Or *don't* inherit from the base - you're not specializing anything, you're just referring to constants. There's no call for inheritance here.

Comment: Let's say I have three-deep inheritance:
BasePageClass->RefinedBasePageClass->Page.

I want to be able to define a set of constant strings (querystring keys) in each of them and have them somehow available to the Page as one collection of constant strings.  I'm still not sure how to pull this off.

Comment: @Jon, while I agree that this is not a problem that inheritance was _intended_ to solve, it is a possible solution to the problem presented. In a way you can say that you are specializing something - the collection of query key constants that should be available to a specified Page.

Answer (score 4):

You can't inherit from structs, ever - and partial types don't *inherit* from each other anyway. They're just multiple source files combined to create a single type.

I don't know about the details of ASP.NET pages anyway, but the point is that you couldn't have multiple partial types each using the same "base" type but combining with it to form different types. The multiple source files declaring the same partial type are simply combined to form *one* and only one type.

It seems you're only doing this to share constants though - that strikes me as a poor use of either partial types or inheritance. Just have a `CommonQueryKeys` static class and reference it appropriately.

Comment: @Developer Art: I can't say I agree, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks John.  That confirmed my guess.  I apologize for my word choice.  You're absolutely right, partial types don't inherit from each other.  However, in light of the page inheriting from the base page and the use of partial structs, I wasn't quite sure how to title my question.

Comment: I'm not really sure what "artistic expression in the code" is meant to convey.

Comment: A CommonQueryKeys static class would lump all the query keys for my various pages together, though. The reason I went down this road was to try and be able to define which specific keys were used at the page level.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe so.

My understanding on partial classes is that all of the partials that share the same name within an assembly will be attempted to be combined. In your case, it won't know that how you're combining, and will have lots of duplicated names.

You could achieve a similar effect with an abstract class though, although you would need a different name/scope class for each page